# Indexing and optimization of where clause based on datetime field

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

I have a database with more than a million of rowset data. When I execute this query it takes hours, mostly due to pageIOLatch_sh. There are currently no indexing. Can you suggest the possible indexing in where clause. I believe it should be on datetime as it is used in where as well as order by , if so which index to use.

```
if(<some condition>)
BEGIN
select <some columns>
From <some tables with joins(no lock)>

WHERE

    ((@var2 IS NULL AND a.addr IS NOT NULL)OR
        (a.addr LIKE @var2 + '%')) AND
    ((@var3 IS NULL AND a.ca_id IS NOT NULL) OR
        (a.ca_id = @var3)) AND
    b.time >= @from_datetime AND b.time <= @to_datetime AND
    (
            (
                b.shopping_product IN ('CX12343', 'BG8945', 'GF4543') AND
                b.shopping_category IN ('online', 'COD')
            )
            OR
            (
                b.shopping_product = 'LX3454' and b.sub_shopping_list in ('FF544','GT544','KK543','LK5343')
            )
            OR 
            (
                b.shopping_product = 'LK434434' and b.sub_shopping_list in ('LL5435','PO89554','IO948854','OR4334','TH5444')
            )

            OR 
            (
                b.shopping_product = 'AZ434434' and b.sub_shopping_list in ('LL54352','PO489554','IO9458854','OR34334','TH54344')
            )
    )AND

    ORDER BY 
        b.time desc
ELSE
BEGIN
select <some columns>
From <some tables with joins(no lock)>
where <similar where as above with slight difference>
```

Comment: please make clear which DBMS you are using. You tagged both - mysql and sqlserver

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2005

Comment: If you have no indexing, I would guess the problem is joins, which you have no included in the question.

Comment: first take indexes on these :shopping_product  and shopping_category sub_shopping_list , and secondly u can try on the date , after that see the execution plan. (or would be better to create partition on the time column)

Comment: hi thomas,could u explain in detail what exactly should be the indexes

Comment: Try to open SSMT and press ctrl+L. That will generate the exaplain plan and in most cases it will generate indexes recommendation for you.

Comment: OR are hard to optimize.  Try pulling conditions up into the join.  Can get rid of one or with isnull(@var3, a.ca_id) = a.ca_id

Comment: Use "Set statistics io on" and run the SQL. That will tell you which table is responsible for most of the I/O -- and that's what you should also index.

Comment: Blam : what about condition a.ca_id IS NOT NULL??it is not checked by ur approach

Answer (score 0):

Okay then,

I said "first take indexes on these : shopping_product and shopping_category sub_shopping_list , and secondly u can try on the date , after that see the execution plan. (or would be better to create partition on the time column)"

I'm working on oracle, but the basics are the same.

You can create 3 distinct indexes on that cols : shopping_product, shopping_category, sub_shopping_list . Or you can create 1 composite index for that 3 cols. The point is you need to examine the execution plan which one is the most effective for you.
Oh, and here is a.ca_id column (almost forget), you need an index for this too.

For the date column i think you would better create a partition instead of an index.

Summary, two ways: - create 4 distinct index (shopping_product,shopping_category,sub_shopping_list, ca_id) , create a range typed partition on the date column
                   - create 1 composite index (shopping_product,shopping_category,sub_shopping_list) and 1 normal index(ca_id) , create a range typed partition on the date column

Answer (score 0):

You probably should learn about indexing if you're dealing with tables of this size. It's not a trivial process. JOIN operations are a big deal when sorting out which indexes you need.  Read this.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

In the meantime, if your date-range is highly selective (that is, if

```
 b.time >= @from_datetime AND b.time <= @to_datetime
```

chooses a reasonably small fraction of the rows in your database) you should try the following compound index.

```
b.shopping_product, b.time
```

If that doesn't help, try

```
b.time
```

by itself.   The idea is to structure your index so the server can do a [range scan.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges) Without a knowledge of your whole query, there's not much else to offer.